# PHP - FIELD MATCH With Multiple Word

Tags: php, regex, function, match

I'm having trouble with a php function.

I'm working on a wedding site, with a page where the guests confirm the presence at the wedding.

I structured a module where they put the NAME, but they could change the position of lastname and name

:::::

Example

The name on invitation is Mario Rossi Family
but they could write :

Mario Rossi Family, Rossi Family, Mario Rossi ....

:::::

... so I need a php function that check if the name inserted matchs with, or contains, multiple values as "Mario" "Rossi" "Family" .....

Please, how can I do?!

Thank you for your time.

Best regards.

Comment: Hi Rhino!
Thanks for your fast reply!

I tried this :

// Get values from form
$name=$_POST['nome'];
$guest=$_POST['invitati'];
$email=$_POST['email'];

if ($name == 'Mario Rossi Family' || $name == 'Mario Rossi' || $name == 'Rossi Family') {

and it works good...but in this case I have to write every possible alternative of the name ... I want to simplify ...

Comment: have you saved your guest list in database?

Comment: No ... I would work just on a php page ... but if you say that is simple working on a db and you can give me a suggest I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I read all the comments on this question.

I understand that you are working only with PHP.
If I am right that is the reason you are afraid to put all the names and you are right.

I sincerely suggest to avoid such an approach.

A DB on the backend, like Mysql, is not difficult to setup, manage and connect with php.

If you do that you could use some simple autocompletion query, so that when the invited person type, the corresponding string from DB is suggested.

Regards

Comment: Yes I agree with you ... but the client says that some guests are not familiar with internet, so he wants that in every case... not in the case of a typing error...

Comment: Reaching a page with a form to fill is not more complicated of reaching a page with a check box. Ticking a box is less complicated than writing a string... I would try to make this clear.

Comment: Ok, I got it. But I don't want to show a page with a list...otherwise everybody could tick a name and proceed ...

Comment: It's good...but is similar to the other I was working on ... I would write just a list of words to check... 
\\:::
Example of list
(family, rossi, mario, caruso, paolo, enrico, bianco)
:::\\
So the function can validate various guests that could use the same word as Mario Rossi , or Bianco Family, or Paolo Bianco, or Mario Caruso, or Caruso Family.

I cannot be more clear than this...

Comment: I really appreciate what you are doing for me ... thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing your guess list is in db so this could be the possible solution:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE CONCAT_WS('', firstname, middlename, lastname) LIKE '%keyword%'
```

Comment: Than where is your guess list stored against which you want to match the entered value ?

Comment: I was workin on this // --- if ($name == 'Mario Rossi Family' || $name == 'Mario Rossi' || $name == 'Rossi Family') { --// It works good ... but in this case I have to write every possible alternative ... I want to simplify...

Comment: But how do you know if user enters "Mario" than you have to check against "Mario Rossi Family" only ? Is this fixed ?

Comment: I just want that the function checks if they enter one or more of words that are in MARIO ROSSI FAMILY ... so MARIO ROSSI, or ROSSI MARIO, or ROSSI, or ROSSI FAMILY ... But I don't want to write every possible alternative ... there is a way to write various words as MARIO, ROSSI, FAMILY and the function check it?

Comment: Try this $alternatives = explode(" ", $name) and the check in_array($userenteredvalue, $alternatives) if you get true than it is valid. $name should be equal to the value against which you want to check. Also  if you want it case insensitive than convert all to lower or upper case and than check.